# Automapper: map child object (list of object) getting data from db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have these classes:

```
public class Tournament
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<Prize> Prizes { get; set; }
  ...
}

public class Prize
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RankPosition { get; set; }
    public Stuff PrizeStuff { get; set; }
}

public class Stuff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public string StuffImagine { get; set; }    
}
```

A tournament class can have several prizes in form of a list;
one prize is associated to a Tournament and RankPosition is the winner (set to 1), the second and the third.
STUFF is a sql server table where are registered all the items that a "RankedPosition" wins in tournament.

My problem is to fill the object STUFF giving only the ID from the client.

The json from client is like this:

```
{
  "Name":"Test",
  "Rule": "this is a rule",
      "OtherProperty": "Just another property",
  "PrizePool":
  [
    {
        "RankPosition": "0",
        "Prize": 
        {
            "ID": 1
        }
    },
        {
        "RankPosition": "1",
        "Prize": 
        {
            "ID": 2
        }
    },
        {
        "RankPosition": "2",
        "Prize": 
        {
            "ID": 3
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case I want to set my objects of class STUFF using above client JSON and save STUFF objects to db.

How can i call a CreateMap method from a SOURCETOURNAMENT class to TORUNAMENT
in way that PRIZES list can map the inner object STUFF from db?

Source and destination PRIZES object are identical.

UPDATE:
I tried to use Automapper.Collection as suggested, but i can't figure how to do.
This is the real code:

```
// SOURCE
public class TournamentParameters
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PremioGiocatore> Montepremi { get; set; }
    ... Other props
}

// DESTINATION
public class DataTournamentParameters
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PremioGiocatore> Montepremi { get; set; }
    ... Other props
}

// Prize for the first & second in the tournament
public class PremioGiocatore
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PosizioneClassifica PosizioneClassifica { get; set; }
    public Premio Premio { get; set; }
}

// Registry of Prizes
public class Premio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }
}
```

In the Startup of the Api I have the mapper configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize((cfg) =>
{
    cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
    cfg.SetGeneratePropertyMaps<GenerateEntityFrameworkPrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<Contesto>>();
});
```

I try to map the source object on the destination one:

```
public int Create(TournamentParameters info)
{
    DataTournamentParameters dataInfo = _mapper.Map<TournamentParameters, DataTournamentParameters>(info);
    ...
}
```

Since that Source and Destination are basically equal i don't know how to create a map to allow to fill my List destination starting from a source that have just an ID as explained above.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have an existing list of objects (from JSON), where only the id is set and you have another list of all full items (from DB). Now you need to update your objects from json source to be filled from the the db list objects. Sounds like a perfect job for https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection

Comment: @Oliver, i follow your suggest, but with no luck. I updated the scenario with the real code.

Comment: My thoughts on this would be you need to get the data from the database before doing the mapping. It's been a while since I've used Automapper to this degree, but trying to do DB work inside mappings can lead to trouble and performance issues.

Comment: @matt_lethargic: I would have done it, but it's interesting to know how to use AutoMapper.EntityFramework properly based on my code.